# Imitate Math.Round for GnuMP library in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

I downloaded for myself `GnuMP` library: https://gnumpnet.codeplex.com/ which behind the curtains uses `gmp.dll` which is wrapper for https://gmplib.org.

It has type Real, which is used for high precision calculations. In other project I have double and decimal type, which I want to replace with Real.

I need to replace `Math.Round()` with customized round for Real ( type in  gnump.net). Did anybody tried to implement Round but for Real of `Gnump`.

Comment: Have you tried implementing it yourself via `Floor`, `Trunc`, and/or `Ceiling`? If not, go do so. If so, let us know what you're having a problem with.

Comment: Yes,  I tried. But for Floor, Trunc and/or Ceiling which are provided by GnuMP didn't have as input parameter precision.

Comment: I need implementation for Math.Round(Real r, int precision). Basic Floor, Trunc, Ceiling doesn't take precision as second parameter.

Comment: Can you include your `Round(Real r)` implementation you already have and specify in the question that you want to be able to specify the precision, and any other requirements? That would make this a good question, and one that I have an idea of how to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found an mathematically correct answer:

```
public static Real Round(Real r, int precision)
{
     Real scaled = Real.Pow(10, precision + 1);
     Real multiplied = r*scaled;
     Real truncated = Trunc(multiplied);
     Real lastNumber = truncated -  Trunc(truncated/10)*10;

     if (lastNumber >= 5)
        {
             truncated += 10;
        }
        truncated = Trunc(truncated/10);
        return truncated * 10 /(scaled);
}
```

When I say mathematically correct I mean that following code:

```
 Real r = 2.5;
 r = Real.Round(r, 0);
```

will give 3.  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx Math.Round will give "round to even" (so called banker's rounding), but I for my task need mathematical round.

Comment: Correct, by default `Math.Round()` rounds to the nearest even number, but there are options you can pass in to produce other results